# What is the mechanism of APTES mono-layer formation on glass substrates?

Tags: surface-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, polymers

The reagent [APTES](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/440140?lang=en&region=US) is a fairly common "ink" for microcontact printing, a technique that forms covalent bonds between the silanols found on the surface of the glass and the silane in the the APTES. It's also been demonstrated that the mono-layer then polymerizes somewhat, forming bonds between neighboring silanols.

- What is the mechanism by which the printing and polymerization occur?
- What is the reason for using APTES instead of a more reactive trichlorosilane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's two links ([1](http://www.ipen.br/biblioteca/2004/10220.pdf), [2](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/la061240g)) that show the simple scheme on forming monolayers. The essential figure is also shown here.

[image: Here is the essential figure from the latter paper if you don't have access]

For the second part of your question... I can only point out [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/poc.372/pdf) that describes which properties change, if you make the molecules more bulky or add chloride, etc. I would guess that APTES has well known properties and they are "neutral" regarding common applications.